# lite-server error while running angular2-quickstart in windows

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am new to angular started angular2 from official site.

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart (quickstart example).

node.js and npm versions are as recomended.

i am facing this error can any one help me on this.

```
**[1] [BS] Serving files from: ./
[1] [BS] Watching files...
[1] events.js:154
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1]
[1] Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
[1]     at exports._errnoException (util.js:893:11)
[1]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:182:32
)
[1]     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:348:16)
[1]     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
[1]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
[1]
[1] npm
[1]  ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
[1] npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\node
js\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "lite"
[1] npm
[1] ERR! node v5.11.1
[1] npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
[1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[1] npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`
[1] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[1] npm ERR!
[1] npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite script 'lite-server'.
[1] npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
[1] npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quicksta
rt package,
[1] npm ERR! not with npm itself.
[1] npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
[1] npm ERR!     lite-server
[1] npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project wi
th:
[1] npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
[1] npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
[1] npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
[1] npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
[1]
[1] npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
[1] npm ERR!     C:\BackUp\projects\projects\Angular2.0\angular2-quickstart\npm-
debug.log
[1] npm run lite exited with code 1**


[enter image description here][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi check your Environment variable and Add the path C:\Windows\System32.

Hope it will help you :)